# Rails I18n randomly loads wrong locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-i18n

The Rails app uses I18n. Users will be using the site in English and the site will randomly load in Spanish.

The application only switches locales in two places.

1. The application.rb has a method that switches locales based on the domain name.
2. There is a mailer that uses the with_locale method to switch locales based on the recipient's locale. This is done because a user whose primary locale is English, may send a message to a user whose primary locale is Spanish.

Here is the mailer method for a message notification:

```
 class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
    def message_notification(message_id, recipient_id)
        @message = Message.find(message_id)
        @recipient = @user = User.find(recipient_id)

        I18n.with_locale(@recipient.locale) do
          mail(
            to: @recipient.email,
            subject: I18n.t('app.new_message.subject',
            name: @message.sender.name),
            from: I18n.t('app.notifier.from')
            ) do |format|
              format.html { render layout: 'notifier-single' }
          end
        end
      end
   end
```

The app uses Sidekiq with Redis to process delayed jobs. So, the method above is delayed like so:

```
Notifier.delay.message_notification(self.id, recipient.id)
```

I wondered if something about the way Sidekiq handles threads might be causing this.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

From this page on the Sidekiq wiki:
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting

"aws-sdk (According to a somewhat old post in the discussion group, this gem is thread-safe with the exception of the use of autoload. More details here. Explicitly calling AWS.eager_autoload! during initialization should allow it to be used with Sidekiq)"

The app uses Amazon SES to deliver mail, by way of the aws-sdk gem.

I added `AWS.eager_autoload!` to the initializer. I will watch and see if the problem continues to persist (I haven't found a way to replicate or test it). That said I'm not sure if that would be related or not so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Sidekiq is actually running in a separate process, it should not influence your application in any way. It is maybe a stupid question, but do you have some partial caching in your views?

Comment: You can give as an argument the locale to `I18n.t`, something like this: `I18n.t('app.notifier.from', locale: @recipient.locale)`. Try to use it and see if it fixes the issue

Comment: @YuryLebedev I am using some partial caching, but that isn't the problem. When the locale switches, it is appending the locale to the URL (e.g. "/es") and the whole page is in the new locale, not just the partials.

Comment: @MrYoshiji my understanding is that the `with_locale` method does the same thing, but is less verbose. Also, the problem isn't with the locale in the emails. It is that the site switches to a new locale randomly.

Comment: did you ever find out what the problem was? i'm experiencing the same thing

Comment: I have the the same problem and could not find any working solution!